# how to efficiently run 10-15 threads concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to run multiple threads concurrently, where each thread is computing value for a particular point in time and returning a result. I was thinking of using the Executor class but it seems am not doing it correctly. I was wondering if this piece of code is correct for that. Or what is the best way of doing this?

```
ExecutorService tasker = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    for(double t = 0.0; t<=5.0; t = t + 0.50 ){ // t is time interval
        tasker.execute(new MyThread(t));
    }
```

Comment: @Richard. does this really mean i have different threads computing for different time intervals? i have been a little bit confused with how executors work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need to pass a Thread inside the execute method.
Instead you need to pass a Runnable object, like so:

```
ExecutorService tasker = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
for(double t = 0.0; t<=5.0; t = t + 0.50 ){ // t is time interval
    tasker.execute(new MyRunnable(t));
}
....
....
class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{
    MyRunnable(double i)
    {
       System.out.println(i);
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `t` a `double` rather than an `int`

Answer (score 1):

To truly run 10-15 threads concurrently you need to have 10-15 free cores.  However, if you have this many free cores, you need to ensure you have a pool with at least this many threads and at least this many tasks.

For CPU bound processes, the optimal number of threads is often the number of cores you have. (Sometimes double with hyper-threading)

Something to watch out for is loops which use `float` or `double`  These types can have rounding error which accumulates with every iteration.  You are far better off using an integer and calculate your value.

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
   double t= i/2.0;
   tasker.execute(new MyRunnable(t));
}
```